# Remote WebDAV hard disk loses connection when copying thereto

Tags: network, hard-drive, mount, webdav, remote-disc

From my 2018 MacBook Pro I connect to a remote hard disk (located in other town) via WebDAV HTTPS protocol. The remote hard disk is Synology RackStation 2414RP+. Whenever I try to copy files larger than some 2 GBs to the hard disc, I lose the connection, the hard disk stays mounted though. Sometimes the connection gets back itself. This also happens when I calculate an md5 hashsum of a file larger than some 2 GBs or when I use grep command on such bigger files on the hard disk.

I'm using the latest macOS Catalina and the Synology hard disk is updated to the latest Synology OS.
The same thing happens also when I connect to the hard disk from Windows 10, so it's not macOS specific.
I have also tried so far mounting the hard disk using [ocsmount for WebDAV](https://ocsmount.com/macos-webdav-mount.html), [Mountain Duck](https://mountainduck.io/) and [ExpanDrive](https://www.expandrive.com/), where the connection is even more unstable using these.

The only time I was able to get a stable connection and could comfortably copy large amounts of data (hundreds of GBs) was when I connected to the hard disk using [Cyberduck](https://cyberduck.io/). This is not a long-term solution though as I need to have the hard disk mounted in the file system.

I suspect there must be something wrong in the settings of the Synology hard disk, maybe some limits... I have no idea, though. Synology is not my cup of tea.
I don't have direct access to the Synology settings, my friend does.

Does anyone have at least any idea how I could solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!